# AWS Sagemaker and Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS Sagemaker endpoint and I am trying to call it using the Java SDK. However I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClient.beforeClientExecution(Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;
at com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClient.invokeEndpoint(AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClient.java:150)
at TestAmazon.main(TestAmazon.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

When I run the invoke-endpoint on the CLI it works as expected.

The code:

```
InvokeEndpointRequest invokeEndpointRequest = new InvokeEndpointRequest();
invokeEndpointRequest.setContentType("application/x-image");
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(read_buf);

invokeEndpointRequest.setBody(buf);
invokeEndpointRequest.setEndpointName("imageclassification-ep--2018-04-17-19-47-00");
invokeEndpointRequest.setAccept("application/json");

AmazonSageMakerRuntime amazonSageMaker = AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClientBuilder.defaultClient();
InvokeEndpointResult invokeEndpointResult = amazonSageMaker.invokeEndpoint(invokeEndpointRequest);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you have a dependency conflict somewhere.

Comment: I checked so many places but when you said that I double checked my pom and I found the error after updating all my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue to my problem it was that I was using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.83</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Instead of the latest version 1.11.313

Answer (score 0):

Anyone reading this thread and wanting to use SageMaker and Java V2 (not V1), see this GitHub location:

https://github.com/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/sagemaker

There are many examples of how to work with this API. For example, the following code example demonstrates how to start a model training job for Amazon SageMaker.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.SageMakerClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.S3DataSource;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.DataSource;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.Channel;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.ResourceConfig;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.TrainingInstanceType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.CheckpointConfig;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.OutputDataConfig;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.StoppingCondition;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.AlgorithmSpecification;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.TrainingInputMode;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.CreateTrainingJobRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.CreateTrainingJobResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.SageMakerException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
//snippet-end:[sagemaker.java2.train_job.import]

/**
 *  To setup the model data and other requirements to make this Java V2 example work, follow this AWS tutorial prior to running this Java code example.
 *  https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/
 */

public class CreateTrainingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    CreateTrainingJob <s3UriData><s3Uri><trainingJobName><roleArn><s3OutputPath><channelName><trainingImage>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    s3UriData - The location where the training data is located (ie, s3://trainbucket/train.csv).\n\n" +
                "    s3Uri - The S3 path where you want Amazon SageMaker to store checkpoints (ie, s3://trainbucket).\n\n" +
                "    trainingJobName - The name of the training job. \n\n" +
                "    roleArn  -  The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the IAM role that Amazon SageMaker uses.\n\n" +
                "    s3OutputPath  - The output path located in a S3 bucket (i.e., s3://trainbucket/sagemaker).\n\n" +
                "    channelName  - The channel name \n\n" +
                "    trainingImage  - The training image.";

       if (args.length < 7) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
       }

        /* Read the name from command args */
        String s3UriData = args[0];
        String s3Uri = args[1];
        String trainingJobName = args[2];
        String roleArn = args[3];
        String s3OutputPath = args[4];
        String channelName = args[5];
        String trainingImage = args[6];

        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        SageMakerClient sageMakerClient = SageMakerClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        trainJob(sageMakerClient, s3UriData, s3Uri, trainingJobName, roleArn, s3OutputPath, channelName, trainingImage);
    }

    //snippet-start:[sagemaker.java2.train_job.main]
    public static void trainJob(SageMakerClient sageMakerClient,
                                String s3UriData,
                                String s3Uri,
                                String trainingJobName,
                                String roleArn,
                                String s3OutputPath,
                                String channelName,
                                String trainingImage) {

        try {
            S3DataSource s3DataSource = S3DataSource.builder()
                    .s3Uri(s3UriData)
                    .s3DataType("S3Prefix")
                    .s3DataDistributionType("FullyReplicated")
                    .build();

            DataSource dataSource = DataSource.builder()
                    .s3DataSource(s3DataSource)
                    .build();

            Channel channel = Channel.builder()
                    .channelName(channelName)
                    .contentType("csv")
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .build();

            // Build a LIST of CHannels
            List<Channel> myChannel = new ArrayList();
            myChannel.add(channel);

            ResourceConfig resourceConfig = ResourceConfig.builder()
                    .instanceType(TrainingInstanceType.ML_M5_2_XLARGE) // ml.c5.2xlarge
                     .instanceCount(10)
                    .volumeSizeInGB(1)
                    .build();

            CheckpointConfig checkpointConfig = CheckpointConfig.builder()
                    .s3Uri(s3Uri)
                    .build();

            OutputDataConfig outputDataConfig = OutputDataConfig.builder()
                    .s3OutputPath(s3OutputPath)
                    .build();

            StoppingCondition stoppingCondition = StoppingCondition.builder()
                    .maxRuntimeInSeconds(1200)
                    .build();

            AlgorithmSpecification algorithmSpecification = AlgorithmSpecification.builder()
                   .trainingImage(trainingImage)
                    .trainingInputMode(TrainingInputMode.FILE)
                    .build();

            // Set hyper parameters
            Map<String,String> hyperParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hyperParameters.put("num_round", "100");
            hyperParameters.put("eta", "0.2");
            hyperParameters.put("gamma", "4");
            hyperParameters.put("max_depth", "5");
            hyperParameters.put("min_child_weight", "6");
            hyperParameters.put("objective", "binary:logistic");
            hyperParameters.put("silent", "0");
            hyperParameters.put("subsample", "0.8");

            CreateTrainingJobRequest trainingJobRequest = CreateTrainingJobRequest.builder()
                    .trainingJobName(trainingJobName)
                    .algorithmSpecification(algorithmSpecification)
                    .roleArn(roleArn)
                    .resourceConfig(resourceConfig)
                    .checkpointConfig(checkpointConfig)
                    .inputDataConfig(myChannel)
                    .outputDataConfig(outputDataConfig)
                    .stoppingCondition(stoppingCondition)
                    .hyperParameters(hyperParameters)
                    .build();

           CreateTrainingJobResponse jobResponse = sageMakerClient.createTrainingJob(trainingJobRequest);
           System.out.println("The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the training job is "+ jobResponse.trainingJobArn());

        } catch (SageMakerException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[sagemaker.java2.train_job.main]
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)